# error when attempting to remove values from regressionin r

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have been doing some playing around with regressors in r, however, I have run into a problem. when trying to remove coefficients from a regressor.

```
newRegressor$coefficients <- newRegressor$coefficients[-1]
```

at first, I thought that this approach succeeded, as printing the `newRegressor$coefficients` shows that the first coefficient has been successfully removed. This later caught me off guard however when I was using this regression later, and when error checking I realized that the first element was still their in the summary.

Is there any other way to remove the first coefficient within a regressor, **without** re-declaring it using the lm() function (or any other function along the same lines)?

In case of any confusion, there are no error messages. Also here are the screenshots of the coefficients of `summary(newRegress)` before and after running the line

```
newRegressor$coefficients <- newRegressor$coefficients[-6]
```

Before:

[image: Coefficiants Before]

After:

[image: Coefficiants After]

Answer (score 0):

What is the error showing? If you want to remove all rows of column 7, you can write 
newRegressor$coefficients <- newRegressor$coefficients[,-7]

Comment: newRegressor$coefficients is not two dimensional, as the code in my example shows. Additionally, there are no error messages associated with this, the problem is that it is not actually removing the line.